# Normalize Count Measure in Tableau

Tags: visualization, tableau-api, n-gram

I am trying to create a plot similar to those created by [Google's ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams). I have the ngrams that correspond to year, but some years have much more data than others; as a result, plotting from absolute counts doesn't get me the information I want. I'd like to normalize it so that I get the counts as a percentage of the total samples for that year.

I've found ways to normalize data to ranges in Tableau, but nothing about normalizing by count. I also see that there is a count distinct function, but that doesn't appear to do what I want.

How can I do this in Tableau?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Edit: 
Here is some toy data and the desired output.

Toy Data:

```
+---------+------+
| Pattern | Year |
+---------+------+
| a       |    1 |
| a       |    1 |
| a       |    1 |
| b       |    1 |
| b       |    1 |
| b       |    1 |
| a       |    2 |
| b       |    2 |
| a       |    3 |
| b       |    4 |
+---------+------+
```

Desired Output:
[image: Screenshot 2017-04-26 12.39.36.png]

Comment: Why not just create a function that sums the values you want and divides by the period total?

Comment: plot the absolute counts, and then right click on your measure field and choose quick table calcs, pick % of total. then experiment with the "compute using" setting via right click as also

Comment: P.S. People can give you better assistance on SO if you post a little sample data along with a very precise question

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @AlexBlakemore. I've updated the post with toy data and a mockup of the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put [Year] on the Columns shelf, and if it is really a Date field instead of a number - choose any truncation level you'd like or choose exact date. Make sure to treat it as a discrete dimension field (the pill should be blue)

Put [Number of Records] on the Rows shelf. Should be a continuous measure, i.e. SUM([Number of Records])

Put Pattern on the Color shelf.

At this point, you should be looking at a graph raw counts. To convert them to percentages, right click on the [Number of Records] field on the Rows shelf, and choose Quick Table Calc->Percent of Total. Finally, right click on [Number of Records] a second time, and choose Compute Using->Pattern.

You might want to sort the patterns. One easy way is to just drag them in the color legend.

[image]

Comment: This gets me close. The missing piece is that when a pattern occurence drops to 0 for a year, the line does not go to zero. [Here is the plot I get with my toy data following your instructions](https://s30.postimg.org/iixfghz7l/Screenshot_2017-04-26_13.43.37.png)

Comment: Right click on your field on the row shelf, choose format, and set how you wish to handle null values. At the bottom of the format pane. See the end of this help section https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/help.htm#formatting_specific_numbers.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; that seems like it should do exactly what I want, but setting the format [like this](https://s22.postimg.org/9lxsmiza9/null_marks_as_default_value.png) has no apparent effect. I also tried modifying the calculation by wrapping the numerator in IFNULL(..., 0), but that didn't work either.

Comment: I revised my answer to suggest a different approach using bars in case you find that more intuitive.

Comment: Thanks  @AlexBlakemore! That helped me confirm that what I was doing was correct. It turns out, my lines weren't working because I mistakenly hadn't set the year to a Date datatype. Now that they are a Date in Tableau, everything works perfectly.